# File::stat returns defined on <control> character 0x00 - perl - feature or bug?

Tags: perl, stat

# This is perl 5, version 22, subversion 1 (v5.22.1) 
   # built for x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi

```
use File::stat;
my $wchar   = chr 0;
my $unicode = sprintf 'U+%06X', ord $wchar;
my $file    = './'.$wchar;
my $sb      = stat($file);

if($sb){
    printf "File is %s, size is %s, perm %04o, mtime %s\n",
    $file, $sb->size, $sb->mode & 07777,
    scalar localtime $sb->mtime;
    printf "unicode is $unicode\n",
}
```

----- Gives me.. ----

```
File is ./^@, size is 4096, perm 0775, mtime Mon Aug 14 20:34:21 2017
unicode is U+000000
```

---

I'm a bit baffled. Any suggestions why this happen. Is it a feature or bug?

Comment: Seems it returns true for directory

Comment: The `$wchar` prints nothing, and I am getting stat for the `./` directory, in fact. It seems that `'./'.$wchar` is `stat`-ed as `./`. Is that what is going on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`stat` passes the string to the OS untouched. The OS expects a NUL-terminated string, so it sees `./` when you pass `./␀`.

Before 5.20, this used to be the case for `open` as well. It now returns error `ENOENT` instead.

```
$ perlbrew use 5.20.0t

$ ls -1

$ perl -e'open my $fh, ">", "abc\0def" or die $!;'
No such file or directory at -e line 1.

$ perlbrew use 5.18.2t

$ ls -1

$ perl -e'open my $fh, ">", "abc\0def" or die $!;'

$ ls -1
abc
```

I consider this lack of consistency a bug.

Comment: Changed part of my answer

Comment: For what it's worth, PHP used to have the same issue with many file handling functions. It was fixed in PHP 5.3: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=39863

Comment: a pragma baffle :) :)

Comment: It makes me think of how easy it is to make inconsistency by thinking of 0x00 as false rather than a value, which is actual is. If val is `! defined` , then and only then it is no value.

Comment: 1) I don't know what you mean by "a pragma baffle". If you are suggesting the creation of a pragma that decides how to handle NULs, I disagree. The behaviour should be changed to also give an error in strings containing NUL. 2) It doesn't make any sense to say that undefined isn't a value. 3) `"\x00"` is true, not false. 4) Even if it was false, we're not talking about `"\x00"` because that returns an error on all versions of Perl.

Comment: `perlbug` can be used to file bug reports.